# R: Simulating Correlated Coin Flips

Tags: r

I am working with the R programming language.

I want to simulate coin flips such that:

- If heads, then next head with p = 0.6 and tail = 0.4
- if tails, the next tails with p = 0.6 and heads = 0.4

Using the 'markovchain' package in R, I did this as follows:

```
library(markovchain)

# transition matrix
P <- matrix(c(0.6, 0.4, 0.4, 0.6), byrow = TRUE, nrow = 2)
rownames(P) <- colnames(P) <- c("H", "T")


mc <- new("markovchain", states = c("H", "T"), transitionMatrix = P)

# Generate states
states <- rmarkovchain(n = 100, object = mc, t0 = "H")

# Print 
table(states)
```

The output looks something like this:

```
> states
  [1] "H" "T" "T" "H" "T" "T" "T" "H" "H"
```

**My Question:** Can someone please show me how I can do this in base R?

I think I need to:

- create an empty list of size "n"
- assign n[1] = H or T with prob 0.5
- write an IFELSE statement that says `n[i] = ifelse(n[i-1] == "H", sample(c("H", "T"), prob = c(0.6, 0.4), sample(c("H", "T"), prob = c(0.4, 0.6))`

But I am not sure how to do this.

Can someone please show me how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here it is.

```
Fair=function() sample( c(rep('H',5), rep('T',5)),1)
A=function() sample( c(rep('H',6), rep('T',4)),1)
B=function() sample( c(rep('H',4), rep('T',6)),1)
x=Fair()
for (i in 1:10) x=c(x,ifelse(tail(x,n=1)=='H', A(), B()))
print(x)
```